# Seminaire Chevalley, 1958, exp no. 2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

I was trying to read [Seminaire Chevalley, 1958, exp no. 2](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/browse?id=SCC_1958__3_) and I encountered some notation I don't understand.

T and U are varieties.  He defines Z as a closed subvariety of $U \times V$ such that for all $t \in T$, $Z.(U\times t)$ is defined.

I wonder if anyone knows what $Z.(U\times t)$ denotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, from the context, that it is the [intersection product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory#Intersection_theory_in_algebraic_geometry).

Comment: If you look for "intersection" in the pdf you can see from context that Chevalley writes the intersection product as `X.Y` (e.g. Proposition 4)